# Maven project - Could not calculate build plan

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

While creating maven project , eclipse giving below error..I'm using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 and maven version(mvn -version)

`Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T12:37:52-05:00)
Maven home: C:\maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"`

`Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5`

What am i missing and whats wrong here ? Please avise.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Sample1</groupId>
  <artifactId>Sample1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: Show us your pom.  Specifically, your `maven-resources-plugin`

Comment: I have maven-plugin in eclipse , So when creating new maven project itself i'm getting above error and once create the project successfully , it will create pom.xml file automatically.

Comment: First build your project on command line if it works you can continue in Eclipse.